# Regular Expression for recognizing negative and non-negative values

Tags: regex

What is the appropriate regular expression for recognizing negative and non-negative values?

Something like this:

```
#define DECIMAL_NUMBER_REGEX @"[1-9][0-9]*|0"
```

Answer (score 5):

Not sure why this is tagged "iOS", but a regular expression for recognizing non-negative integers may be

```
\+?0|[1-9][0-9]*
```

And for negative integers:

```
\-[1-9][0-9]*
```

(assuming `-0` is treated as non-negative)

If you specifically want to create regular expressions for iOS development, you can use the NSRegularExpression class:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\+?0|[1-9][0-9]*" options:0 error:NULL];
```